# PC can be Ping'd by IP and name, show in network list but windows 11 says Network Path Not Found

Tags: network-shares

Firstly, we have added a new pc to the network and changed drive letters on the problem PC to point to the QNAP device where the data was being backed up. All our data was on D: which we changed to Z: and created a network map as D: to the QNAP all good. When establishing the new PC it was established in a similar manner with mapped D: and local Z: shared this can be accessed across the network sharing Z:

Attempts to connect to the old PC fail as in the title. We have followed all the recommended steps checking network sharing, even adding a second sharename adding common user with full permissions. We have also flusheddns, reset winsock etc and in desperation tried SMB1 all without success.

Running the free version of advanced IP scanner we see all devices connected to the network with PC shares prefixed with a > which can be expanded to show the shared drives. Funny thing here the old pc has no >, as if no shares exist. Double clicking the pc name opens explorer with the network mapped D:\documents folder which is not expected as it is NOT shared on the PC.

On both PC's "users" folder points to network mapped D: with the exception of Desktop which is local users Z:

Both PC's connect to Workgroup dynamic IP's

Any advice what to try next greatly appreciated.